# Monaco-Editor HoverProvider get the word mouse hovers over

Tags: javascript, typescript, monaco-editor

How can I get the word I am hovering over in Monaco editor ?

I want to show a specific value over a word that is saved in my array. So when the user hovers over the word I want to compare that word with the words saved in my array and then show the saved value of that word.

I know these two methods:

```
model.getValue() // gets all the text stored in the model
model.getValueInRange({startLineNumber, startColumn, endLineNumber, endColumn}) // gets the value in Range, but I don't now the start and end column.
```

Here is my code, I just need the help with the method getValueInRange:

```
 public variableHoverProvider = <monaco.languages.HoverProvider>{
    // this is for getting the values on hover over context variables and shortcuts
    provideHover: (model, position, token) => {
        if (model.getLineContent(position.lineNumber).trim() !== '') { // if only whitespace don't do anything
            let current = this.store[this.store.length - 1]; // just the place where I store my words and there values

            console.log(model.getValueInRange({
                startLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
                startColumn: 1, // this is the information I am missing
                endLineNumber: position.lineNumber,
                endColumn: 5  // this is the information I am missing
            }));

             // TODO: I have to find somehow the word the mouse is hovering over
            // let getMatchingContextVariableValue = current.contextVariables.map(ctxVariable=>{
            //     if(ctxVariable)
            // });

            let test = current.contextVariables[22].value;

            return {
                contents: [
                    { value: test }
                ],
            };
        }
    }
};
```

Has anyone maybe a good Idea how I can get the text I am hovering over ? Or how to calculate the startColumn and endColumn in getvalueInRange method ?

Here is the [Monaco-Editor HoverProvider Playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html#extending-language-services-hover-provider-example)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to go through [`model.getValueInRange`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.itextmodel.html#getvalueinrange) you can simply use [`model.getWordAtPosition`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.itextmodel.html#getwordatposition).

Conveniently the [`HoverProvider`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.hoverprovider.html) is called with `model` and `position` so that's no problem.

To provide a minimal example that can be executed by the monaco playground:

```
monaco.languages.register({ id: 'mySpecialLanguage' });

monaco.languages.registerHoverProvider('mySpecialLanguage', {
    provideHover: function(model, position) { 
        // Log the current word in the console, you probably want to do something else here.
        console.log(model.getWordAtPosition(position));
    }
});

monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: '\n\nHover over this text',
    language: 'mySpecialLanguage'
});
```

Note that this returns a [`IWordAtPosition`](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.editor.iwordatposition.html) object which has three properties:

> #### endColumn: number
>
> The column where the word ends.
>
> #### startColumn: number
>
> The column where the word starts.
>
> #### word: string
>
> The word.

So to get the word as string at the hovered position, you need to access `model.getWordAtPosition(position).word`.

Comment: I was searching for this for so long.  I knew that there was a easy way as I can see that the monaco editor is placing correctly the popup. Thanks.